# RapidMiner - binomial to integer conversion

Tags: binary, integer, numerical, rapidminer

I need to pass data to Neural Net operator. Some attributes are binomial and Neural Net does not accept binomial data type,  however it accepts integer. 
There is no Binomial to Integer (Numerical) type conversion operator. So how can I convert this ?

Thanks for an answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "Nominal to Numerical" operator which also works for binominal types.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Nominal to Numerical operator. It is however kind of tricky -- you need to select the "value type" selector and then select binominal. If you select single or subset, only polynominal atributes are going to be offered to you, at least in my version.